# image-sprite size is bigger than container, how to fit it into a smaller container

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-sprites

The size of the sprite is bigger than the container, without using the  tag is there any method to fix the size to fit the container

Dimension  of the image-sprite is 562px (x5) width x 562px height

[main-desktop.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VKyZ.png)

```css
.container_outer{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}
.chrome-part, .ie-part, .firefox-part, .opera-part, .safari-part{
  background-image:url("main-desktop.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:562px;
  width:562px;
  float:left;
}
.container_outer > .chrome-part{
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
.container_outer > .ie-part{
  background-position: -562px 0px;
}
.container_outer > .firefox-part{
  background-position: -1124px 0px;
}
.container_outer > .opera-part{
  background-position: -1686px 0px;
}
.container_outer > .safari-part{
  background-position: -2248px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_outer"> 
  <div class="ie-part"></div>
  <div class="firefox-part"></div>
  <div class="opera-part"></div>
  <div class="safari-part"></div>
  <div class="chrome-part"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you upload the sprite somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `background-size` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the [`background-size` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and the `cover` value. This scales the sprite to the maximum size of the container. I've made an example with the containers being 200px squares.

```css
.container_outer{
  height:200px; /* assuming a square container 200px */
  width:100%;
}
.chrome-part, .ie-part, .firefox-part, .opera-part, .safari-part{
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VKyZ.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;  /*  as large as possible */
  height:100%;
  width:200px;  /* assuming a square container 200px */
  float:left;
}
.container_outer > .chrome-part{
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
.container_outer > .ie-part{
  background-position: -200px 0px;
}
.container_outer > .firefox-part{
  background-position: -400px 0px;
}
.container_outer > .opera-part{
  background-position: -600px 0px;
}
.container_outer > .safari-part{
  background-position: -800px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_outer"> 
  <div class="ie-part"></div>
  <div class="firefox-part"></div>
  <div class="opera-part"></div>
  <div class="safari-part"></div>
  <div class="chrome-part"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I had to put the height of the image to 100% and not the actual height which is 562px and width to be same as the container width. background-size: cover and background position based on the 200 width calculation...Got it.. Thanks again :)